# Write in MySQL database when something happens?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm building a game with javascript where you can walk and pick up things, right now it works fine but it doesn't save the things you have picked up on my database so when you quit the game you lose your progress.

I need to save to my database every time the user walks into something (when a div has a certain position). Right now there is a big javascript IF that basically deletes the item from the map.

Is it possible to make the javascript run the PHP code that writes in the database? How could I do it?

Comment: I think you should read up on AJAX.

Comment: You want to look into Ajax to make asynchronous calls to your server without changing the webpage and loosing your game state.

http://www.destraynor.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/29-AJAX-for-the-beginner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would do it is simple.

Every time the player does an action, have your script make an *ajax call to the server to save the location* (or what ever you are saving). You can just add a function to the part of your code, so when it is called, it sends the request in the background and saves the value to your databse. The only thing if that you would have to split the ajax requests up, so you only do one every 5-10 seconds. If you dont do this, then you would basically DDoSing you server.

Comment: I think even the most basic web servers could handle more than 0.2 requests per second :P

Comment: And they are only doing something causes 1 request per second

Answer (score 2):

Since Javascript is client-side code, you can't simply call PHP (server-side code) with it. What you can do is post to a page that runs PHP code, using AJAX for instance.

Answer (score 1):

you need ajax

http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html